# iOS 8.3 causes custom keyboard to freeze without error

Tags: swift, ios8.3

I have a custom keyboard in the app store and it has been there for a while now without problems. After the 8.3 update however, the keyboard seems to always freeze after one stroke input. This happens in the simulator too, but there is no error and the program claims to be running fine. I can't find any reason for the app to stop functioning, especially considering how well it worked before iOS 8.3. I wish I had more info to give, but this is why I'm asking here because I'm desperate at this point. Does anyone have ANY info that might help?